# Feature Request: Non-game, no-edit Stack Overflow

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, edits, reputation

I think it would be nice to have an opt-out version of Stack Overflow that removes the gaming "reputation" points and lowers this site back to the original purpose without all the extra fluff.

Enabling this option should also remove the ability of others to "edit" these opt-out users' questions, as I've found over time that this feature is one of the most annoying and misused features involved with Stack Overflow. If I worded a question poorly or if I straight up asked a terrible question, one should probably just ignore the question or perhaps ask for clarification in the comments.

People editing others questions only stands to curb user education (learning to ask better questions, use better/more-descriptive wording, etc) and often can lead to someone hijacking the question (in some cases where they change the question so much the desired answer is never reached)

Furthermore, the "reputation" aspect of this site is a major point of contention for many users, more people trying to "game" the site than use it as an actual resource.

Basically what I'm asking for here, is not to remove any of these features, as I know so many of the more fanatical Stack Overflow users will cry foul, but to allow a user to opt-out of many of the fluff that Stack Overflow has added over the years.

Frankly, to me, I care more about figuring out my problem and providing help to those who might need it than imaginary points that prove nothing else than I know how to "game" a site and have a lot of spare time.

Comment: Would it be wrong of me to edit this question to improve it's readability?

Comment: So... You want a version of SO that's more of a forum? Because that is how it reads to me...

Comment: Would it be wrong of me to edit your comment to remove that rogue apostrophe @PWKad? ;)

Comment: If you don't care about rep and edits, don't edit anyone's questions and don't pay attention to rep. Simple.

Comment: Still, can't stop people from editing my questions, I'm assuming that would upset other users too much, without being able to meddle in my affairs :)

Comment: If someone edits your question and the edit overstepped the boundaries of normal editing (changed the meaning etc) roll it back and if they keep doing it flag it for moderator attention. You shouldn't be too concerned with other users fixing your grammar, it's not personal, and we're not here to teach the world English.

Comment: I can't care less if some people don't want to have reputation, but I think not being able to edit other people's posts is counter-productive and harmful to the over-all quality of stackoverflow.

Comment: I don't care about fixed grammar, fixed punctuation or anything rather semantically based. What annoys me is when users start adding links, adding and changing the code snippets and removing information that they deemed was "unnecessary"

Comment: This request isn't clearly specified. Do you want a completely separate site that doesn't have reputation or allow edits. Or do you want the two groups of users to coexist on the same site?

Comment: If you think a user is making radical, inappropriate edits to your questions, you can rollback the edits, and if there's a dispute, you can flag your question for moderator attention to resolve it, or bring the issue up here on Meta.

Comment: The stuff that you're calling "extra fluff" and not part of the original purpose of the site are actually some of the core ideas that the founders intended to include from the very start as core principles of the site.  Editing was not tacked on later as a frilly benefit; having the community collaboratively improve all content was a core founding value.  The same thing can be said about voting on posts.

Comment: Somewhat related: [My complaint about reputation introducing impurities in motivation.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42481/the-problem-with-extrinsic-motivation) But I don't at all understand the problem with editing. In fact, editing stands as my favorite teaching tool on the network and I wish it was used more often and more wisely.

Comment: What I'm not clear about is how allowing users to opt-out of earning reputation is supposed to do anything, unless you were trying to propose a second version of SO where *no* users earn reputation? Otherwise, you'd have this second group of users running around the current SO with no reputation, but because they have no reputation, the system is unable to determine whether or not to grant those users on-site privileges. Which there's nothing wrong with, but perhaps it won't really improve the site. I guess that kind of depends on what you were expecting to get out of it...? I don't know.

Comment: I agree with Cupcake. Opting out of reputation won't fix any of the problems you associate with reputation. You're free to ignore your reputation score, or give it away in bounties if it really bothers you. Also, editing and reputation have been a part of Stack Overflow from day one, so removing them would not return the site to its origin. It's always been this way.

Comment: [Your only question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24559733/revisions) was edited to fix your formatting mistakes.  Where is this rash of "editors who hijack questions and make it completely different than what was originally asked", and how does it compare to "editors who fix badly formatted or worded questions and make them easier to read"?  How hard it is to find examples?  (As a bonus, if you find them, we can fix them)

Answer (score 74):

> People editing others questions only stands to curb user education (learning to ask better questions, use better/more-descriptive wording, etc)

The history of the Internet is littered with the corpses of communities that thought they could demand compliance from new members without showing them how. Editing is hands-on education for those willing to learn and a means of salvaging the efforts of those answering even when the asker never learns anything.

I signed on to the Stack Overflow beta six years ago for *one reason only*: the promise of a Q&A site that let answerers edit questions into something decent. As far as I'm concerned, a Stack Overflow without editing isn't Stack Overflow; if that's what you want, get a blog or set up PHPBB.

Answer (score 39):

At the very very ***core*** of why Stack Exchange was created was to create a safe haven from much of the "random" *mis*-information and poor content posted on the internet. We accomplish that by assuring that all posts are vetted (and improved where warranted) by a peer group of fellow experts in the subject.

We simply cannot place a *do-not-touch* sign on a post because the user doesn't *want* their stuff vetted, changed, or improved in any way. There's an implicit expectation that what you see here ***has*** been vetted by a peer group, so allowing people to *opt out* of peer review goes squarely against the purpose of creating these sites in the first place.

Comment: Then I suppose my search will continue for a programming site with a good community.

Comment: Happy trails! (write if you work)

Comment: @Mike you can try checking out a Google Group maybe? Or a Google+ community? I've noticed that they both host specific communities for things like JavaScript, Ruby, etc. You can also maybe try Quora, but I'm not sure how much activity there is with regards to programming questions over there. Oh yeah, there are various sub-reddits dedicated to programming topics too (such as JavaScript), so maybe you can check those out?

Comment: Sub-reddits. *shudders*.

Answer (score 25):

#### Editing

> Enabling this option should also remove the ability of others to
>   "edit" these opt-out users questions, as I've found over time this
>   feature is one of the most annoying and misused feature involved with
>   Stack Overflow. If I worded a question poorly or if I straight up
>   asked a terrible question, one should probably just ignore the
>   question or perhaps ask for clarification in the comments.
>
> People editing others questions only stands to curb user education
>   (learning to ask better questions, use better/more-descriptive
>   wording, etc) and often can lead to someone hijacking the question (in
>   some cases where they change the question so much the desired answer
>   is never reached).

Editing is a key feature of this site, and is one of the things that distinguishes it from traditional discussion forums (not to imply that Stack Overflow is some kind of "discussion forum", mind you). Anyone can edit (or suggest an edit) to improve the quality of unclear questions or answers.

If you feel that someone has made an inappropriate edit to your content, you can always roll the edit back, and if it becomes an issue with other users, you can flag your post for moderator attention to resolve the dispute, or bring the issue up here on Meta.